# GParted Freezes the whole system Help ASAP

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, suspend, gparted

I’m running a gparted session right now and it seems to have frozen the system. Mouse movement works, and that's about it. Clicking has no response, super key does nothing, ctrl alt t does nothing and the clock doesn't even tick. atm of posting this question gparted is still running, and probably active because the USB stick is still hot.

**leading up to the issue**

I used a USB stick to run ubuntu without installing. Currently, GParted is stuck on resizing the system partition (/) of the ubuntu installed on my laptop

**possible reason**

I’ve done similar resizing before and was successful. the only thing I did differently was I shut the lid of the laptop, I know, dumb mistake :(. It did not go to sleep although the screen went blank. No login or anything, but may have been an issue for gparted.

Should I force restart? What would that do? please provide some advice :) ask for more detail if needed, I will be active.

update: I unplugged my mouse and plugged it in again and it doesn't work anymore. thats not a good sign is it.
[image: current state]

Answer (score 0):

**Do not close the lid while running gparted!**

I force restarted my computer after waiting for quite a long time. It worked out fine, luckily, probably since that the process just started when I closed my lid. The partition it was working on showed up as gray in half of it, and normal(white and yellow) in the other half. The resize and everything worked fine.

Moral of the story: Do not close the lid while running gparted!